# Should access to the shared database in an application be channelled through a single microservice?

Tags: mongodb, api, microservices

Consider a sample application **APP**. This is comprised of microservices **A**, **B** and **C** and a shared NoSQL mongo database. These microservices make API calls to each other and say the application **APP** completes every transaction as a co-ordination actions between these services. Throughout each transaction, each service A, B and C require reading and writing data from one or more of collections of the shared database at some point.

Should application **APP** limit database access to only one service say **A**, and make other microservices **B** and **C** access database through **A** such that there is a single gateway to the shared database and only one microservice is allowed access to the database.
OR
Should each microservice **A**, **B** and **C** have access to independently access the database?

Assumption: Let's assume that there is no chance of two services simultaneously modifying any record in the database as each operation is transactional and happens in stages.

Answer (score 0):

If several microservices are using/managing data from the same tables/collections then mostly likely it is an indication of a bad design.

Each microservice should be responsible from a set of entities means set of collections.

None of the other components in the system should have access to those collections in anyway other than getting data through the responsible service.

But that doesn't mean you should create a set of rest endpoints or smth similar to expose the data from database to external services.

You should just serve your resources with a proper contract in between components.